# HTML/CSS table right align text not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, alignment

Again, Internet Explorer is not getting easy on me. I have a table with two cells in the same row. I want to display some text aligned to the left (first cell), and another one aligned to the right (second cell). This is working fully in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE all the text appears left-aligned:

```
<table width="660px">
<tr>
    <td align="left" width="160px">Text 1</td>
    <td align="right" width="160px">Text 2</td>
</tr>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​

After some research I wondered if I should put it on the CSS, so I changed it to:

HTML:

```
<table class="anchors" width="660px">
<tr>
    <td class="left" width="160px">Text 1</td>
    <td class="right" width="160px">Text 2</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
table.anchors td.left
{
    text-align: left;
}

table.anchors td.right
{
      text-align: right;
}
```

It still doesn't work in IE (version 9, at least). Does anybody has a hint on this? Should I be using something else (a div, e. g.)?

Comment: Do you mind making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Seem to work fine in IE9 even initial design. Add border to your table to get more visuals on how text is aligned.

Comment: The quickest way to solve these types of problems is to use the IE dev tools (F12).  Then you can make changes to the css and see the live results as you go.

Comment: What about the rest of the page?  Is IE being forced into quirksmode or compatibility mode because of some other problem?  Are you using the proper `doctype`?  Does your HTML validate?

Comment: Its a bug This link may help you [TEXT ALIGN BUGS](http://haslayout.net/css/Text-Align-Bug)

Comment: The page says its affects IE 6 and 7, but the OP has stated IE 9

Comment: Do you have a `doctype` in your page?

Comment: op said ,need to work at least in ie9.

Comment: +1 for a great question. IE is so hard to support compared to other browsers.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick & kind answers. The problem was obvious: the width of the td's, as many of you pointed out. I had each <td> with 330 pixels, somehow changed it & didn't noticed it. Sorry for bothering you. Although, I've changed some details to have more standardized HTML, but I'll check the validity of the HTML because part of it is being generated by the software I'm using (SSI Web).

Comment: And just for the record, I had the DOCTYPE already defined. And by the way, the correct code: http://jsfiddle.net/jaff/97cbr/2/

Next time I'll have to pay more attention before asking for help, this time I can't blame IE, I can only blame myself :]

Thank you all again,
João

Comment: It was something else, prash. See my comments to the original post for details. Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: I am sorry jaff, you are right,i didn't read your question perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is syntactically malformed (`width` attributes take numeric or percentage values, not with `px` units), though this pardoned by browsers. More seriously, you are setting conflicting requirements: the table should be 660 pixels wide but consist of two 160 pixels wide cells. It is not surprising that browser behavior is inconsistent.

However, IE 8 and IE 9 behave like other browsers when in “Standards Mode”. Otherwise, in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html), anything may happen, and you cannot call it a bug, because the document is non-conforming. So add an adequate doctype declaration.

In addition, it is best to avoid conflicting requirements. If you need to set a total width on the table in pixels, so be it. Then either set column widths so that they add up or, simpler, set e.g. the widths to 50% (for a two-column table that should be balanced).

Comment: You were right, Jukka. look at the comments to my original post above. Thanks all the way for the corrections!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/6jvnQ/

Can you change the width of the table so that it is as wide as the two cells? I suspect you get differing results because the weird widths.

Comment: It was exactly that, Jonas. See my replies to my own post for details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this:

padding-left:22% or 22px or any length